# Экспорт в Excel формы ввода данных PyQt c помощью Openpyxl

Tags: python, pyqt, layout, qlineedit, qgroupbox

Возникла проблема с экспортом формы ввода данных из *PyQt5* в *Excel* c помощью *Openpyxl*.
Основной "затык" в динамически добавляемых `QLineEdit` и `QGroupBox`.

Я находил как присваивать новым добавляемым через кнопку `QLineEdit` уникальные названия и считывать с них значения в файл Excel, но никак не получается провернуть это к целому блоку QGroupBox с вложенными в нем динамически добавляемыми `QLineEdit`.

Надеюсь внятно изъяснился, я только учусь.
Например:

```
import sys
from datetime import datetime
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QLineEdit, QLabel, QGroupBox, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QDialog, QGridLayout, QComboBox, QDateEdit
from PyQt5 import QtCore


class TextApp(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        ''' задаем сетку и основные блоки '''
        self.maingrid = QVBoxLayout(self)
        firstlay = QHBoxLayout(self)
        secondlay = QHBoxLayout(self)

        '''добавляем информацию в шапку'''
        maininfo = QGroupBox('main info', self)
        maininfogrid = QGridLayout(self)
        fio = QLabel('fio', self)
        fioline = QLineEdit(self)
        date = QLabel('date', self)

        dateline = QDateEdit(self)
        dateline.setDate(QtCore.QDate.currentDate())
        dateline.setCalendarPopup(True)

        maininfogrid.addWidget(fio, 1, 0)
        maininfogrid.addWidget(fioline, 1, 1)
        maininfogrid.addWidget(date, 2, 0)
        maininfogrid.addWidget(dateline, 2, 1)

        maininfo.setLayout(maininfogrid)

        '''добавляем основные кнопки'''
        addwork = QPushButton('add work', self)
        addwork.clicked.connect(self.add_work)
        printreport = QPushButton('print report', self)

        self.maingrid.addLayout(firstlay)
        self.maingrid.addLayout(secondlay)

        firstlay.addWidget(maininfo)
        secondlay.addWidget(addwork)
        secondlay.addWidget(printreport)

        workwidget = NewWork()
        self.maingrid.addWidget(workwidget)

        self.show()

    def add_work(self):
        workwidget = NewWork()
        self.maingrid.addWidget(workwidget)

class NewWork(QGroupBox):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initwork()

    def initwork(self):

        thirdlay = QHBoxLayout(self)
        workinfo = QGroupBox('work info', self)
        materialinfo = QGroupBox('material info', self)
        machineinfo = QGroupBox('machine info', self)
        personinfo = QGroupBox('person info', self)

        '''задаем вспомогательную сетку данных о работе, расстоянии и стороне'''
        self.workgrid = QGridLayout(self)
        work = QLabel('work', self)
        workline = QLineEdit(self)
        self.workgrid.addWidget(work,       2, 0)
        self.workgrid.addWidget(workline,   2, 1)

        pk_begin = QLabel('pk begin', self)
        pkbline = QLineEdit(self)
        self.workgrid.addWidget(pk_begin,   3, 0)
        self.workgrid.addWidget(pkbline,    3, 1)

        pk_end = QLabel('pk end', self)
        pkeline = QLineEdit(self)
        self.workgrid.addWidget(pk_end,     4, 0)
        self.workgrid.addWidget(pkeline,    4, 1)

        storona = QComboBox(self)
        storona.addItems(['choose side', 'left side', 'right side', 'all side'])
        self.workgrid.addWidget(storona,    5, 0, 1, 0)

        workinfo.setLayout(self.workgrid)

        '''создаем основную кнопку, вызываем функцию по клику и добавляем в основную сетку'''
        machinelay = QGridLayout(self)
        machine = QPushButton('add machine', self)
        machine.clicked.connect(self.add_machine)
        machinelay.addWidget(machine,       1, 0, 1, 0)

        '''создаем вспомогательные сетки добавляемых полей техники и присоединяем к основной сетке техники'''
        self.machinename = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.machineline = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.machinenumber = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.numberline = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.owner = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.ownerline = QVBoxLayout(self)

        machinelay.addLayout(self.workgrid,      2, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        machinelay.addLayout(self.machinename,   2, 1)
        machinelay.addLayout(self.machineline,   2, 2)
        machinelay.addLayout(self.machinenumber, 2, 3)
        machinelay.addLayout(self.numberline,    2, 4)
        machinelay.addLayout(self.owner,         2, 5)
        machinelay.addLayout(self.ownerline,     2, 6)

        '''присоединяем разметку к группировке'''
        machineinfo.setLayout(machinelay)

        '''устанавливаем принадлежности сеток'''
        thirdlay.addWidget(workinfo)
        thirdlay.addWidget(materialinfo)
        thirdlay.addWidget(machineinfo)
        thirdlay.addWidget(personinfo)

        self.show()

    def add_machine(self):
        '''создаем кнопки и поля, задаем фиксированную ширину и присоединяем к вспомогательным сеткам'''
        machine_add = QLabel('machine', self)
        machine_add.setFixedHeight(20)
        self.machinename.addWidget(machine_add)

        line_add = QLineEdit(self)
        line_add.setFixedHeight(20)
        self.machineline.addWidget(line_add)

        number_add = QLabel('number', self)
        number_add.setFixedHeight(20)
        self.machinenumber.addWidget(number_add)

        line_add1 = QLineEdit(self)
        line_add1.setFixedHeight(20)
        self.numberline.addWidget(line_add1)

        owner_add = QLabel('owner', self)
        owner_add.setFixedHeight(20)
        self.owner.addWidget(owner_add)

        line_add2 = QLineEdit(self)
        line_add2.setFixedHeight(20)
        self.ownerline.addWidget(line_add2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = TextApp()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Вы не правильно применяете layout к widgetу.
   Все подклассы QWidget могут использовать макеты для управления своими дочерними элементами.

   Функция QWidget::setLayout() применяет макет к виджету.

   `self.mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()`

   `self.setLayout(self.mainLayout)`

   или

   `self.mainLayout = QVBoxLayout(self)`

   **это одно и то же!**

   Рекомендую вам почитать
   https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html и
   https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setLayout
2. я немного упростил структуру вашего приложения,
   но все равно достать данные способом, который вы задумали,
   будет очень тяжело.

   я наполнил метод `print_report` некой функциональностью,
   которая сработает по клику на кнопку 'print report'.

   В первой части - показано как вытащить данные из
   `QGroupBox('main info')` и это только цветочки...
   как вытаскивать данные из других `QGroupBox` страшно и подумать.
3. Предлагаю вам попробовать создать, например словарь, `self.mainDict = {}`
   и заполнять его по ходу дела.

   Во второй части - метод `print_report` немного показано как
   доставать данные из этого словаря.

---

```
import sys
from pprint import pprint as pp
from datetime import datetime
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QLineEdit, \
    QLabel, QGroupBox, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QDialog, QGridLayout, \
    QComboBox, QDateEdit, QFormLayout
from PyQt5 import QtCore


class NewWork(QGroupBox):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(NewWork, self).__init__(parent)
        self.row = 2
        self.parent = parent
        self.numNewWork = parent.numNewWork
        print(self.numNewWork)
        self.setStyleSheet("background: teal;")
        self.hide()

    def initwork(self):
        workinfo = QGroupBox(f'work info {self.numNewWork}')
        materialinfo = QGroupBox(f'material info {self.numNewWork}')
        machineinfo = QGroupBox(f'machine info {self.numNewWork}')
        personinfo = QGroupBox(f'person info {self.numNewWork}')

        workline = QLineEdit()
        pkbline = QLineEdit()
        pkeline = QLineEdit()
        storona = QComboBox()
        storona.addItems(['choose side', 'left side', 'right side', 'all side'])

        self.workgrid = QFormLayout(workinfo)
        self.workgrid.addRow('work', workline)
        self.workgrid.addRow('pk begin', pkbline)
        self.workgrid.addRow('pk end', pkeline)
        self.workgrid.addWidget(storona)

        machinelay = QGridLayout(machineinfo) 
        machine = QPushButton('add machine')
        machine.clicked.connect(lambda ch, lay=machinelay: self.add_machine(lay, r=self.row))
        machinelay.addWidget(machine, 1, 0, 1, 0)

        thirdlay = QHBoxLayout()
        thirdlay.addWidget(workinfo)
        thirdlay.addWidget(materialinfo)
        thirdlay.addWidget(machineinfo)
        thirdlay.addWidget(personinfo)
        
        self.parent.mainDict[f'work info {self.numNewWork}'] = (workline, pkbline, pkeline, storona)
        self.parent.mainDict[f'machine info {self.numNewWork}'] = []
        
        
        return thirdlay                                      # ---->>>

    def add_machine(self, lay, r=2):
        #print(lay, r)
        name = lay.parent().title() 
        
        line_add = QLineEdit(self)
        line_add1 = QLineEdit(self)
        line_add2 = QLineEdit(self)
        
        lay.addWidget(QLabel('<h3>machine</h3>'), r, 1)
        lay.addWidget(line_add,                   r, 2)
        lay.addWidget(QLabel('number'),           r, 3)
        lay.addWidget(line_add1,                  r, 4)
        lay.addWidget(QLabel('owner'),            r, 5)
        lay.addWidget(line_add2,                  r, 6)        
        self.row += 1
        
        self.parent.mainDict[name].append([line_add, line_add1, line_add2]) 
        

class TextApp(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.mainDict = {}
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        maininfo = QGroupBox('main info')
        maininfogrid = QFormLayout(maininfo)
        fioline = QLineEdit(self)
        dateline = QDateEdit(self)
        dateline.setDate(QtCore.QDate.currentDate())
        dateline.setCalendarPopup(True)
        maininfogrid.addRow('fio', fioline)
        maininfogrid.addRow('date', dateline)

        addwork = QPushButton('add work', self)
        addwork.clicked.connect(self.add_work)
        printreport = QPushButton('print report', self)
        printreport.clicked.connect(self.print_report)

        secondlay = QHBoxLayout()          
        secondlay.addWidget(addwork)
        secondlay.addWidget(printreport)

        self.maingrid = QVBoxLayout(self)        
        self.maingrid.addWidget(maininfo)
        self.maingrid.addLayout(secondlay) 

        self.mainDict['main info'] =  (fioline, dateline)       

        self.numNewWork = 1
        self.add_work()

    def add_work(self):
        workwidget = NewWork(self)
        thirdlay = workwidget.initwork()                            # <<<----
        self.maingrid.addLayout(thirdlay)
        self.numNewWork += 1
        
    def print_report(self):
        # первая часть
        print(f'\n layout().count() -> {self.layout().count()}')
        print(self.layout().itemAt(0))

        print(f'\t  ->  {self.layout().itemAt(0).widget()} ')
        print(f'\t  ->  {self.layout().itemAt(0).widget().children()}')
        print(f'\t  ->  {self.layout().itemAt(0).widget().children()[2].text()}')
        print(f'\t  ->  {self.layout().itemAt(0).widget().children()[4].dateTime().toString("dd-MM-yyyy")}')
        print(f'{"-"*30}\n')   
        
        # втора часть
        pp(self.mainDict)
        
        print('\nmain info:')
        print('\t', self.mainDict['main info'][0].text())
        print('\t', self.mainDict['main info'][1].dateTime().toString("dd-MM-yyyy"))
        # 'work info 1' 
        print('work info 1:')
        print('\t', self.mainDict['work info 1'][0].text())
        print('\t', self.mainDict['work info 1'][1].text())
        print('\t', self.mainDict['work info 1'][2].text())
        print('\t', self.mainDict['work info 1'][3].currentText())
        # 'machine info 1'
        
        _list = self.mainDict['machine info 1']
        if _list:
            print('machine info 1:')
            for i in _list:
                print('\t', i[0].text(), i[1].text(), i[2].text())
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = TextApp()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]